# How did the Motorola MC68030 and MC68040 come to have the powerful and expensive CAS2 instruction?

Tags: instruction-set, multitasking, motorola-680x0

The CAS2 instruction - *double* compare-and-swap - is an extremely powerful instruction that was coveted for quite awhile (and still is, really) for making lock-free and wait-free data structures - that is, data structures that operate correctly and quickly in the face of concurrent use *without* requiring locks of any kind.

But it is also extremely expensive, as it must *atomically* compare *two* different memory locations against two registers and proceed to update them (still under the atomic constraint) both if and only if both comparisons are equal.

You just can't find it today. (For a number of reasons, including that it would totally nuke performance on a multicore due to the synchronization required.) But it *was* implemented in the 68030 and 68040!

It's in the ["Motorola MC68030 Enhanced 32-Bit Microprocessor User's Manual - 3e (1992)"](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/122366/MOTOROLA/MC68030.html) in section "3.5.1 Using the CAS and CAS2 Instructions", for example.

So my question is:  How, circa the late 1980s (the 68030 was introduced in '87, development must have started at least a year earlier?) did Motorola's engineers (and program managers) come to decide that such an unusual and expensive operation was desirable in their chip?  And that it was higher priority than anything else they could throw in there? In other words, what specific use case(s) did they have in mind, what trends were they aware of, what customer was banging on their door demanding it, ...

(Apparently the first published research AFAIK to use CAS2 (aka DCAS) was in 1991 (Massalin, Pu. A lock-free multiprocessor OS kernel, TR, Columbia University, June 1991); publications on lock free data structures using CAS or LL/SC started around 1991 and interest in DCAS came later, I believe. There was quite a lot of academic research interest in DCAS in the early 90's.)

Comment: Doug MacGregor, Dave Mothersole, and Bill Moyer, "The Motorola MC68020", *IEEE Micro*, Vol. 4, No. 4, July/August 1984, pp. 101-118 : "There are several new instructions which are used to provide system support. The compare and swap (CAS)
and compare and swap 2 (CAS2) instructions allow for locked-bus manipulation of byte, word, or long-word data elements to support system queue and stack functions."

Comment: @njuffa - yes, that's what they do. but for that CAS is sufficient for a stack.  You can do CAS for queues too subject to some limitations. My question is, why go to CAS2?  (Unless the answer is, for a single core microcoded processor, why not, given CAS?)

Comment: It seems to me that it's only caching that makes this difficult at all.  Otherwise it's just a modest sequence of microcode, with the memory bus locked throughout.  Expensive to execute, but not expensive to implement.

Comment: @njuffa - I missed that, thanks for repeating it!  The document I was looking at that sparked this question mentioned only the -30 and -40!  It's even more interesting for the earlier -20!

Comment: And browsing the 68030 manual, I'm not immediately seeing how they intended to enforce coherency of the on-chip caches in a SMP system.  If there was such a mechanism, then it shouldn't be too hard to adapt it to grab two cache lines instead of one.  Or maybe there wasn't, and you were just expected to set all shared regions as uncacheable.

Comment: @NateEldredge - maybe, maybe not - there weren't timing issues (e.g., with coprocessors, or devices)?  I don't know, maybe it was just microcode.  But even so, wasn't microcode space at a premium?  There was nothing else they could have used it for that was more imporant?

Comment: I mean, in order to have CAS in the first place, you already need a mechanism to lock the bus, so CAS2 doesn't need anything more - you just hold the lock for longer.  And was microcode space so scarce?  I'm seeing estimates that the 68020 had on the order of 100 kbits of microcode ROM already, and CAS2 can't have needed all that much.  Everything has an opportunity cost, sure, but it doesn't seem like too much of a leap to recognize CAS2 as something potentially valuable that software can't achieve otherwise.

Comment: Also, back to my point about cache - it looks like the 68020 didn't have a data cache, so CAS2 would seem to have been pretty easy at that point.  And like njuffa says, for the 68030 and later, they had to make it work no matter the cost.

Comment: A second publication by the Motorola folks: Paul F. Groepler and James Kennedy, "The MC68020 32-Bit Microprocessor", *Byte*, Vol. 9, No. 12, November 1984, p. 159-174 : "The MC68020 also offers other new security and system-level instructions. The CAS and CAS2 instructions use the same read-modify-write cycle as the M68000's TAS (test and set). These operations are indivisible and noninterruptible. which ensures data security in single and multiprocessor systems. [...] The CAS and CAS2 instructions are useful for updating system counters and for insertion and deletion from linked lists."

Comment: Just a speculation: I used to program 68000 processor in assembler a lot and I always wondered what the LINK, CHK and CHK2 (and other instructions) where good for. Only later, when I started programming in Ada, it occurred to me that those kind of instructions may have been included in order to support compiler development (in particular for Ada e.g.  CHK is perfect for constraint checks which Ada uses *a lot*). The same may be true for CAS and CAS2 which may be used for tasking in Ada.

Comment: @NateEldredge: At the time CAS2 was engineered into the instruction set, there were no known algorithms to a combination of single CAS operations to safely maintain a doubly linked list without having to acquire a list-wide lock first.  The development of such an algorithm effectively negated the advantage CAS2 offered over CAS.

Comment: @HartmutBraun xdada 040 compiler uses CHK2 to check ranges, that's a fact.

Comment: coming from an amiga background, those instructions can't be used due to the amiga architectures with co-processors and all. Pity.

Comment: As njuffa initially hinted, the manual states in 3.2.11 that some instructions (TAS, CAS, CAS2) are intended to coordinate operations of processors in multi-processor systems, that simple. Those facilities can also be used for other purposes in single processor systems, as per 3.5.1.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, I know that Ada compilers use those instructions, and it *seems* that those instructions have been introduced exactly for the purpose to support high level languages (maybe even requested by compiler producers?) But only when this speculation was true (which I’m not sure of) this would be a proper answer to OPs question.

Answer (score 18):

### TL;DR:

- TS, CAS and CAS2 work thru bus locking
- CAS2 was introduced with the '020, the '030 had to have it for compatibility
- While the 'cost' of locking for a complex operation is high, it's not higher than for simpler versions doing the same
- CAS2 is overall more performant than a series of CAS/TS instructions

*[While all 4 points are valid, the second would rectify the effort on its own]*

---

### The Long Read:

> The CAS2 instruction [...] for making lock-free and wait-free data structures

Not really. CAS2, like CAS and all similar, **are** locking instructions. For them to perform they need to make sure that no other access to the memory locations in question happens during execution.

The are not only atomic within the CPU but in relation to memory as well. For simple write operations these is done by such an operation being already atomic on memory. For more complex the CPU has to

- lock the memory region *before/with* reading and keep locked until the last related write is done.
- Or, more general, lock all of memory access during that time
- Or, most 'primitive' way, with the assumption of the bus system being the only way to access memory for all components in a system doing so.

68k CPUs do exactly the last approach, they take and lock the bus during such a read/modify/write operation.

- For early (68000) versions TS as a byte wide operation was the only such and locking was done by applying *Address Strobe* low over the whole read and write cycle.

This worked fine as it's one and the same address that got read and written, no address change was needed, so AS could be used to lock the bus, saving the need for a dedicated RMW-Lock Signal (*1)

- Later, with CAS2 multiple addresses had to be read/written, thus AS was needed to signal each address, requiring the introduction of RMC (Read Modify Cycle) as a locking signal.

> But it is also extremely expensive, as it must atomically compare two different memory locations against two registers and proceed to update them (still under the atomic constraint) both if and only if both comparisons are equal.

*Per se*, not expensive at all. It's a simple sequence of memory access operation. What you may think about here is effort in cache handling (as mentioned).

> For a number of reasons, including that it would totally nuke performance on a multicore due to the synchronization required.

No it doesn't - or more exact, not more as any other atomic memory operation does. Each TAS has the same issues regarding to multiple cores and memory caching.

> But it was implemented in the 68030 and 68040!

A 030 not compatible with the preceding 020 would have been a bad sell, wouldn't it?

> So my question is: How, circa the late 1980s (the 68030 was introduced in '87, development must have started at least a year earlier?) did Motorola's engineers (and program managers) come to decide that such an unusual and expensive operation was desirable in their chip?

It was already part of the 68020 instruction set - sold as a high performance feature for modern 32 bit OSes. So any 030 design was bound to support it as well - unless Motorola was inclined to get bad press that important instructions at the core of modern OS management had to be replaced by some slower emulation or worse, existing OS couldn't run straight away on the newer faster chip.

> what specific use case(s) did they have in mind

Exactly what you think about: handling linked lists in a most performant way. After all, they are at the core of data handling past the most trivial. Having CAS2 can speed up everything from task switch to data base caching.

> (Apparently the first published research AFAIK to use CAS2 (aka DCAS) was in 1991 (Massalin, Pu. A lock-free multiprocessor OS kernel, TR, Columbia University, June 1991); publications on lock free data structures using CAS or LL/SC started around 1991 and interest in DCAS came later, I believe. There was quite a lot of academic research interest in DCAS in the early 90's.)

Are you sure? CAS style instructions date back to the 1960s. IBM introduced CS (Compare and Swap) with the /370 for all machines in 1970 (*2, *3). CAS2 like operations were as well available on other computers. For example the Siemens X-Series CPUs (/370 based) had a linked list operations (EXST - Execute Stack) that could do the same as CAS2 plus a few more steps like following a linked list until the insertion point was found.

And all of that was done of course in multi processor environments. Heck, that's where the real additional value is gained - let the hardware do synchronisation, not slow software.

The mentioned linked list operations (EXST) extreme potent compared with simple TS and CS operation. Not just in theory but very obvious in practical usage. When the OS finally got modified to take advantage of these instructions, an over all performance increase of OS functions of up to 20% could be seen. Most within the lowest level and thus most often needed ones. After all, an OS is most of it's time occupied with book keeping, mostly walking (*4) and rearranging lists.

So for the performance argument often made against operations like CAS2, is is only true when looking at the single operation compared to what others cost but not looking at the gain realized. Yes, they need to synchronize memory between cache levels and CPUs, but so does each and every 'simple' CAS. But in contrast to a series of CAS that are needed to replace a CAS2, that CAS2 will use less resources.

---

*1 - Intel type bus uses bus lock anyway.

*2 - It was available on certain /360 before.

*3 - By having the 68020 add a CS to the 68000 TS, Motorola more or less just copied IBM move here a decade later as the /360 had a TS (Test and Set) instruction first, to be complemented by CS with the /370.

*4 - The reason why several early CPUs had an indirect addressing feature using a bit within an address word to indicate that another addressing cycle is to be used to follow that address. It removes all the overhead of looping thru a series of high level instructions when all that's needed is a sequence  of memory access cycles.

Comment: The notion of "lock free", "wait free", and "non-blocking" relate to the impossibility that a thread which gets waylaid while performing a sequence of operations might stall another thread indefinitely.  One could design a system to guarantee the length of time a hardware bus lock could be held, an guarantee that the process holding the lock couldn't be waylaid without releasing it.  Although the hardware cost and complexity of CAS2 would go up with the evolution of split bus designs, I think hardware vendors might have kept supporting it were it not for the development of...

Comment: ...single-CAS-based algorithms for doubly-linked-list management which, while more complicated double-CAS-based algorithms, could offer the same immunity to stalling.  Once that happened, the writing was on the wall for CAS2: it was clear that support for CAS2 would become more expensive with succeeding generations, even though the need had largely evaporated.

Comment: Single CS based algos were present way before multi word CS instructions - after all, the issues they handle were present from the very start of multiprocessing.

Comment: Were there *non-blocking* single-CAS algorithms for updating doubly-linked lists?  TAS is sufficient to do almost anything with blocking algorithms, but CAS was added because it allowed *many* tasks to be performed by non-blocking algorithms.  I don't think the set of tasks that CAS could usefully perform with non-blocking algorithms included doubly-linked-list updates until sometime in the 1990s, though I could be mistaken on the date.

Comment: CAS allowed *many* tasks to be performed by non-blocking algorithms that would have otherwise required the use of blocking algorithms.  That was obviously useful.  What I am questioning is whether non-blocking updates to doubly-linked lists were recognized as being among the operations that could be performed in non-blocking fashion using single CAS in the 1980s.  Looking through the dates of references in e.g. https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/srg/netos/papers/2001-caslists.pdf suggests to me that it wasn't.

Comment: @supercat You serious think that since CS was introduced in the 1960s it took 30 years to find a use for? Come on. The usual issue to implement this lock-free occurs when an insert concurrently happened with the deletion of an element where that would point to the newly inserted . This can be prevented by a mark before swap algorithm. Used that already in the early 1980s, but I guess more brillant minds have used  that already way before.

Comment: But they are lock-free; they do not appear in application lock graphs because it is impossible to observe the lock in application code even by handling an interrupt.

Comment: @supercat Lol, that paper looks much like what we did ... Guess we should have spend more time in writing papers than doing our job :))

Comment: @Joshua Well, it always depends on the level looked at. from an (ISA) software level they are lock free, from a CPU, System or microcode level they do use locking and insert the necessary waiting/synchronisation - thus impending performance, albeit on a different level.

Comment: @Raffzahn: What happens with mark-before-swap if the task which performs the mark dies or gets blocked indefinitely before doing the swap?  It may often be more practical to ensure that can't happen than do use a lock-free algorithm which would be robust even if it does, but when the 68020 was being designed I don't think there was any known way to be robust all scenarios if one couldn't guarantee that tasks couldn't get waylaid.

Comment: @supercat The paper you cited does exactly show that mark and swap algo. Just unlike they claim, it's nothing new but has been used about 20 years before (well, I think even before that, as I would not claim to have invented it). And yes, if a process dies before swap, the whole list still works, as the entry to be deleted _is_ already marked as non existent. Easy to ignore when accessed and easy to recover by walking the list.

Comment: What references do you have for a lock-free, wait-free, or non-blocking single-CAS *doubly* linked lists prior to the1986 design of the 68020?  A claim that people hadn't come up with such a thing then doesn't imply people were stupid, but rather that blocking algorithms or data structures other than doubly-linked lists were considered adequate to meet the needs of the time.  I think it's more plausible that no such algorithms were known in 1986 when CAS2 was designed into the 68020 than that the inventors of that chip wasted effort on something that was completely useless.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I wonder if CAS2 was seen as a way of supporting DCAS (double-wide CAS, which is useful and widely supported) which would be essentially as easy to implement as DCAS but more versatile.  The fact that it could support doubly-linked lists may have been touted by marketing people as an advantage, but wasn't the real purpose.  Many CAS-based algorithms can run into an ABA problem unless objects have associated counters, and DCAS often allows such counters to be large enough that they never wrap around.  For example...

Comment: ...if one has a linked list of objects stored in an array with a maximum size of 16,777,215 items, and each item has a 40-bit counter for how many times it has been recycled, one could guarantee that no 64-bit reference value would ever get reused.  If an item that gets recycled a trillion times would be marked as permanently ineligible for any future recycling, and a billion items are allocated per second, that would leak less than four items per hour.  If only a million items are allocated per second, leakage would be about three items per month.